# Do (any) philosophers worry if there can be a priori truths about a changing world?

Tags: philosophy-of-mathematics, existence, metaphilosophy

Do (any) philosophers question how there can be a priori truths about a changing world -- has anyone worried whether this is possible, or if those different modes, of timeless truth and contingent existence, are in some way irresolvable?

I'm asking cos I wondered whether something like *geometry* can be known to apply to shapes coming into and out of existence. What sort of ways, if at all, have philosophers challenged the potentiality of **a priori truth about contingent events**?

I would have thought that any succesful challenge to them, and so I think geometry, would then mean that extension is a fiction, so that occurences in time and space (tokens) are ideal (whether or not that disposes of all physicalisms).

Comment: apologies if this has come up -- but the question seems like one with broad interest

Comment: You appear to be using a priori and necessary as synonymous. For the purposes of your question, can you pick one? (perhaps necessity unless you want to tangle this very tightly with Kant and/or kripke)

Comment: @virmaior i'm not, i'm just calling geometry a priori. i'm particularly interested in geometry, and will edit the question to reflect that -- thans

Comment: in body: `So especially any problems with there being apriori truth about contingent events.` in title: `Do (any) philosophers worry if there can be necessary truths about a changing world?` / are these sentences supposed to express something similar or am I misreading them?

Comment: @virmaior like i said, i'm assuming geometry is a priori

Comment: @virmaior done! though i added more context which may make me sound like a lunatic ;)

Comment: You'll have hard time finding contemporary philosophers who believe in "timeless truths" and necessary a priori. The notion of a priori current in philosophy is relativized, these are fallible structural assumptions needed to obtain and organize empirical content, see [What are the more complex/interesting examples of synthetic a priori statements?](http://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/37726/what-are-the-more-complex-interesting-examples-of-synthetic-a-priori-statements/37733#37733) Geometry is a priori in this sense because one needs to assume it to make measurements.