# Is it, a priori, more likely that an unknown object does not exist than that it does?

Tags: existence, universe, occams-razor

For me, intuitively the answer seems to be yes. But I don't know how this could be justified *a priori*. The hypothesis "x does not exist" seems not to be simpler than the hypothesis "x exists". By the [principle of indifference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_indifference), both options should therefore be assumed to be equally likely. But this doesn't seem right to me.

The question also could be equivalent to this one:

**Is it, *a priori*, more likely that the complexity of the universe is smaller than larger?**

Because a universe where less exists is presumably less complex and vice versa.

Comment: How unknown is the object? If nothing is know at all this becomes is it more likely that there is something rather than nothing, and I'd say that it is overwhelmingly more likely that there is. And sorry, but I am missing why the boldface question is equivalent to the title one, or even how they are connected at all.

Comment: @Conifold A universe where less exists is presumably less complex and vice versa.

Comment: The connection you want to draw suffers from a pretty damning reductio that shows we shouldn't try to figure out whether the universe exists by looking just an a prior argument for the superiority of simplicity: taken to its extreme (and merely a priori), the assumption would seem to imply that nothing in the universe and moreover the universe itself does not exist (by repeated application of the assumption the simpler is more likely)

Comment: @virmaior A priori likeliness doesn't necessarily imply truth.

Comment: Does it imply anything at all?

Comment: "Unknown" says it all: unknown. But if you are nitpicking, ask yourself what the word "likely" means. I do not know, but I think this seemingly trivial subject is huge.

Comment: @virmaior Yes it does, namely how strongly you should expect something. Which in turn can influence your behavior. The principle of indifference (cited above) is an example for this.

Comment: I don't see why it implies `how strongly you should expect something`. At best,1.  it implies  how strongly you should expect something in the total absence of empirical sense data of any kind (hence the *a priori*), but since 2. expectations are about things we sense ... 3. ??? 4. Profit!

Comment: @virmaior I don't know what you mean. The principle of indifference is an a priori principle, just as Occam's razor and probably other principles. These principles tell you which possibility you should prefer, which means: how strongly you should expect something.

Comment: Maybe I'm not following what you're proposing, but I read you as suggesting  this.  (1) assume an *a priori* principle of indifference and (2) assume an *a priori* principle of parsimony.  Then you ask, if we make both assumptions, what happens? My answer: it would be most logical to assume *a priori* that NOTHING exists. But this would be absurd because *a posteriori* we know that something exists. Ergo, it's a mistake to assume both principles *a priori* because the logical outcome of this is absurd.

Comment: Moreover, the principle of indifference tells you to assume equal probabilities, but the *a priori* is a realm where no events occur, so you're just left with percentages across an infinite chain of cascading possibilities -- which have no connection the world.

Comment: That something is unlikely doesn't exclude the possibility that it is true. So I don't know what should be absurd here. You seem to further claim claim that _a priori_ justified beliefs have no effect on the world. But of course they have. Philosophy, especially analytic philosophy, is largely an a priori discipline. Even more so mathematics. They have great effect, they just do not derive their justification from empirical data.

Comment: You will be hard pressed to find a philosopher today who believes in Kantian style justificatory a priori. The "a priori" recognized today are fallible presuppositions, loosely based on past experience, used to build hypothetical explanations and models. The order of justification is reversed, it is the a posteriori success of explanations that justifies the "a priori". If you start from blank slate then the principle of indifference will tell you that x existing and not are equiprobable, but unless you can use this to explain something it goes nowhere.

Comment: pray tell, what on earth does "a priori an unknown object does not exist". can you see the problem?  the propososal ("unknown object") already assumes what you're trying to establish. your question is perfectly meaningless.

Comment: i.e. "an unknown object" already tells us there must be such an object - otherwise it could not be an unknown object.

Comment: p.s. epistemology != ontology. and neither has anything to do with complexity.  what does "small complexity" even mesn?

Comment: @Conifold Most philosophers believe that there is a priori knowledge or at least a priori justification, only a few (followers of Quine's "web of belief") do not. If you mean with "Kantian style" synthetic a priori knowledge you may well be right, but that's not the only form of a priori knowledge (not even for Kant), just look at analytic statements. The principle of indifference to which you refer is in fact believed by many to be justified a priori, e.g. because it is analytic.

Comment: @mobileink If you think that something you don't know anything about can't exist you are a solipsist. Here is more information on the topic: https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/nonexistent-objects/
"Small complexity" means something like "little information needed for a description". You can find more explanation here: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov_complexity If you have further questions you should ask them separately on stack exchange, this gets a little off topic here.

Comment: @max: read harder. i never said that things we do not know cannot exist.

Comment: you cannot ascribe a property like "does not exist" to something that does not exist. indeed "something that does not exist" is preposterous.

Comment: @mobileink Then for you _every_ positive existence statement is true, because "x does not exist" is always false? Because sentences like "Stana Claus does not exist" are supposedly "preposterous"? What about hypothetical (non-)existence statements in science? Well that's a funny view, but doesn't get you very far. Just read the Standford Encyclopedia article on nonexistent objects I posted above.

Comment: And of course existence doesn't have to be a property of an object, e.g. it can also be a fact of whether some singular term x corresponds to an object in the world or not, very similar to the correspondence theory of truth (which instead talks about a correspondence of propositions to facts).

Comment: @Max: no. "Santa clause exists" is meaningful, but it has no truth value. Just like "Time is red."

Comment: @Max also note that the Principle of Indifference is not apriori. in fact it depends on underlying assumptions, which are optional. see https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/dialetheism/

Comment: @mobileink Your view about existence statements is highly controversial which is a reason that you should not state it as a fact. Again, I refer to the article about nonexistent objects. Also you didn't answer my question about hypothetical existence statements which are perfectly common in science. According to your view, such a hypothesis is either true when the hypothetical object exists or neither true nor false otherwise. In the latter case probably every scientist would say the statement is false. You can call them what you like of course, but you risk then being misunderstood.

Comment: As far as I can see the article on dialetheism does not say anything about the principle of indifference. In fact I don't know how you come to the idea that it is relevant here. You say that some statements are "neither true nor false" which amounts to a third truth value "gap" as it is used in the strong Kleene logic (system K3). But in dialetheism there are instead statements which are "both true and false" which amounts to a third truth value "glut" in Priests logic of paradox (system LP). These systems behave differently. So dialetheism is not even compatible with what you said before.

Comment: You are correct that most believe in some form of analyticity, including late Quine, some even believe in synthetic a priori, see descriptions and references in [What are the more complex/interesting examples of synthetic a priori statements?](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/a/37733/9148) But none of them provide a priori justification in the sense that would make your question meaningful. On all of these conceptions, except Kant's, analytic conventions and synthetic a priori can be discarded a posteriori if the explanations they furnish are deemed unsatisfactory.

Comment: @Max: there is no controversy. some logics accept the Law of Exluded Middle, others don't. The principle of indifference does.  if you reject LEM then the PoI is pointless.  You can only assign probabilities to n possibilities if you accept LEM.

Comment: @Max: regarding scientists and "hypothetical existence statements": good scientists (imho) do not traffic in true/false. They worry about support, disconfirmation, etc. Newton's laws turned out to be false, meaning unsupportable.

Comment: If the object is "unknown", and we are to decide on the likeness of its existence upon the fact that it is unknown, we are no longer reasoning a priori.

Comment: just looking at what I expect the question to be maybe there is some subconscious observation of a large or infinite universe containing everything conceivable, or anything ever conceivable, respectively

Comment: I'm not sure, especially as I'm not much of an expert on the subject in any way, but maybe Occam's Razor is what the OP is looking for? The idea that the least assumptions made for a theory would make the theory "better" (or simply put - don't assume more than you need).

Comment: A bacon sandwich in the hand of some Chinese person: Totally unknown to me, but very very likely to exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Frequentist approach**
Hypotheses *x exist* and *x does not exist* are complimentary: the object either exists or does not exist with probability 1 (i.e., 100%)

In research context, if trying to show existence of something, we would take *x does not exist* as the [*null hypothesis*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_hypothesis) and *x exists* as the *alternative hypothesis*. We then would then collect data and estimate (using some model) the probability of the null hypothesis being true. Provided that this probability is lower than *a priori* significance threshold (which we agree upon before collecting the data), we would reject the null hypothesis.

**Bayesian approach**
In Bayesian approach probability is simply our belief in something, which we adjust according to the evidence available. The set of all the things actually existing can be thought of as a subset of all the things imaginable - that is, the subset of the actually existing this is "smaller". We could even strengthen the relation between these two sets by stating that to any actually existing object corresponds an infinite number of imagined ones. That is an arbitrary fruit of imagination, like the notorious [Invisible Pink Unicorn](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invisible_Pink_Unicorn) are more likely not to exist than the other way around.

Answer (score 1):

Well the issue with the principle of indifference is that it only applies if there can be only one item in a set. For instance if you have 4 possibilities that all contradict each other, and thus only 1 can be true, you're looking at a situation where most are false, and it is most likely any one is false. However if you take 4 possibilities that do not contradict each other, and multiple can be true, it is also possible that most or even all of the possibilities are true, and thus you cannot say that it is unlikely for any particular one to be true.

Comment: But that's the point. We actually have here two contradicting possibilities, haven't we? "X exists" and "X doesn't exist" contradict each other for any X.

Comment: That isn't really the meaning of this rule though, and given two possibilities you would only get that there is a 50% chance of something existing, which does not indicate it probably does not.

Comment: But that's exactly what I was asking about: Can it really be rational to treat the hypothetical existence of some x as equally likely as it's hypothetical non-existence, as the principle of indifference seems to suggest? I don't know if you share this intuition, but to me it seems much more likely that an object, of which you do not know anything about whether it exists, does not exist than that it does. To put it in another way: Can it really be rational to expect the hypothetical existence of infinitely many unknown hypothetical objects with probably 50% each?

Answer (score 1):

Before answering this question, one must ask what it means. What does it mean to calculate the probability that A exists? If it is unknown, should it even be given a non zero probability?

It seems to me that the only correct answer is to say that the question itself is **vacuous** and the answer doesn’t seem to map into reality in any meaningful way. For example, if I said that there is a 40% chance aliens exist. What does that mean?

If you take a frequentist approach, it’s clearly meaningless. We don’t have multiple “trials” or worlds where we can test whether or not 40% of them have aliens in them. If you take the subjective approach, which is how much of a belief you should have, you still deal with problems. How, or in what way, can you map your subjective credence into reality? If a person feels like there is a 40% probability that aliens exist, how does this translate into reality? And how does one determine their credence?

Comment: vacuous is a good word in this context.

Comment: The world is full of one-off events, nonetheless you successfully assign probabilities to them all the time.

Comment: Define successful

Answer (score 0):

There are two contexts in which this question can be posed : (1) in your own case and (2) in the case of an agent without experience. 'Unknown' can mean 'unknown that it is' or 'known what it is'. I take it that both senses are implied.

1 If 'a priori' means 'prior to or independent of experience', then (I think) you cannot properly ask the question concerning yourself since you already have experience, and specifically experience of coming to know objects previously unknown in your experience. Inductively, but not a priori, this gives you good grounds for supposing that if you have encountered previously unknown objects in the past then you will also encounter them in future.

2 In the case of someone who has no experience of knowing any objects, I don't see how this person could have any idea of the probability or otherwise of there being unknown objects since no known object has been encountered. 'Unknown object' contrasts with 'known object' but ex hypothesi for this person there are no known objects to contrast with.

3 I think there is a general problem with a priori probability if we take a priori in anything like its standard sense (as above). Probability - likelihood - is probability on the evidence or given certain data :

P (A|B) - the probability of event A, given event B. But a priori, no events are or can be given or any relevant experience. So much is contained in the very idea of the a priori. So while it is interesting to speculate on the probability of there being unknown events, I don't think the a priori is the standpoint from which to approach the question.